# Limiting a List (Listview webpart) to a single User

Tags: 2007, list, development, event-handlers, list-definition

I have a List Definition and I want to limit only 1 specific user to "add new items" to this list, oh by the way its a custom list definition, I was wondering what are the possible ways to accomplish this task. Oh by the way i am using Sharepoint 2007 :).

**EDIT:**

More Like, I just want 1 user(who created the list) to be able to add new Items or Edit/Delete them

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In List permissions Break inheritance and only give this one user contribute rights.

Comment: thanks, I need to add more details to my question, so I gonna ask another question lol